# In bootbox prompt how to increase the size of text area

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootbox

```
bootbox.dialog({
   size:large,
    title: 'Reasons for Rejection?',
    closeButton: true,
    message:
    '<div align="center"> ' +
    '<textarea cols="10" id="tarea" rows="10"></textarea> ' +
    '</div>  ',
    className: "medium",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: 'Cancel',
            className: 'btn-warning'
        },
        success: {
            label: "Save",
             className: "btn-success",
            callback: function () {
                var result=document.getElementById('tarea').value;
                console.log(result)
                if (result) {
                    timesheet_arr = getTimesheet.split('\\s+');
                    Timesheet = {
                        timesheet_arr: timesheet_arr,
                        status: approval_status,
                        comments: result
                    };
                    Timesheet = JSON.stringify(Timesheet);
                    $.post('http://localhost:8000/timer/approvetimesheet/', {'Timesheet': Timesheet},
                        function (returnedData) {
                            console.log(returnedData);
                            if (returnedData == 'Set') {
                                alert('Timesheet was rejected');
                                document.getElementById('accept').disabled = true;
                                document.getElementById('reject').disabled = true;
                            }
                            if (returnedData == 'Own timesheet') {
                                alert('You cannot reject your own timesheet!');
                            }

                        });

                }

            }
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: target the `id` of your `textarea` in your case its `#tarea` and set its `height` `width` accordingly, and remove its `col` and `row attributes

Comment: ok so in css file i have to put these property? hight and width?

Comment: yes, in your CSS file like: `#tarea { width: 300px; height: 150px; }`

Answer (score 2):

Bootbox actually has an option, `inputType`, for the [prompt function](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-prompt-dialog), where you can specify an alternate input type, as seen [here](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#prompt-with-textarea):

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a textarea!",
    inputType: 'textarea',
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

So, you could (somewhat) simplify your code with:

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "Reasons for Rejection?",
    className: 'medium',

    // Change the input type
    inputType: 'textarea', 

    // You can't change the buttons, but you can tweak their style and label (content)
    buttons: { 
        cancel: {
            className: 'btn-warning'
        },
        confirm: {
            label: 'Save',
            className: 'btn-success'
        }
    },

    // Let Bootbox do the work of getting the textarea value
    callback: function (result) {

        // $.trim() isn't really necessary, but it 
        // prevents a user from simply hitting the spacebar and submitting
        if ($.trim(result) != '') {
            timesheet_arr = getTimesheet.split('\\s+');
            Timesheet = {
                timesheet_arr: timesheet_arr,
                status: approval_status,
                comments: result
            };
            Timesheet = JSON.stringify(Timesheet);
            $.post('http://localhost:8000/timer/approvetimesheet/', {'Timesheet': Timesheet},
                function (returnedData) {
                    if (returnedData == 'Set') {
                        alert('Timesheet was rejected');
                        document.getElementById('accept').disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('reject').disabled = true;
                    }
                    if (returnedData == 'Own timesheet') {
                        alert('You cannot reject your own timesheet!');
                    }

                });

        }
    }
});
```

This option was left out of the most recent documentation update (my fault), so it's not obvious unless you actually look at the source code.

Comment: Missed a CSS example to go with it... for example, to set the height of the textarea.

`.medium textarea {
    height: 300px;
}`

Comment: @LuckyEdward Well, "medium" was the class the OP was using, but yes, that would work.

Comment: Which is why I used `medium` in the example. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

**First Approach(using inline CSS)**:

```
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" id="tarea"></textarea>
```

### OR

**Second Approach(using external/internal CSS)** *Recommended*:

```
#tarea { 
   width: 300px; 
   height: 150px; 
}
```

You can set width and height of your textarea.

Comment: You should not encourage anyone  to use *inline CSS*.

Comment: Code Updated.Thanks @vivekkupadhyay

Comment: Glad to help :)